# Concatenate/merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many dataframes and I need to merge/concatenate all of them.
DF1  is the main/master dataframe and then there are many smaller dataframes containing key1 and key2.
There will be only 1 row for a given key1 and key2 pair in all of the dataframes other than the master.
Right now I loop through all the dataframes and merge them one by one into the master/result, so I get many columns_x and columns_y

I do something like this

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
result = pd.merge(result, df3, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
result = pd.merge(result, df4, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

Attached is the picture of the dataframes and the result that I want to see.

Could someone please help me out here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vertically concatenate dataframes that are compatible (df2, df3 and df4) and then merge them horizontally with df1 like this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'key2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
                    'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 1], 'key2': [3, 4], 'D': ['D1', 'D2'], 'E': ['E1', 'E2'], 'F': ['F1', 'F2']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 1], 'key2': [1, 5], 'G': ['G1', 'G2'], 'H': ['H1', 'H2']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 1], 'key2': [2, 6], 'I': ['I1', 'I2'], 'J': ['J1', 'J2'], 'D': ['D1_DF4', 'D2_DF4'],
                    'G': ['G1_DF4', 'G2_DF4']})

df_concat = pd.concat([df2, df3, df4], sort=False, ignore_index = True)
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df_concat, on=['key1', 'key2'], how = 'outer')
df_merge
```

Output :

```
   key1  key2   A   B   C       D    E    F       G    H    I    J
0     1     1  A1  B1  C1     NaN  NaN  NaN      G1   H1  NaN  NaN
1     1     2  A2  B2  C2  D1_DF4  NaN  NaN  G1_DF4  NaN   I1   J1
2     1     3  A3  B3  C3      D1   E1   F1     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     1     4  A4  B4  C4      D2   E2   F2     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     1     5  A5  B5  C5     NaN  NaN  NaN      G2   H2  NaN  NaN
5     1     6  A6  B6  C6  D2_DF4  NaN  NaN  G2_DF4  NaN   I2   J2
```

Comment: It works fine when I have smaller dataset, but I run out of memory for larger dataset. I am talking about 100000 rows with around 90 columns. I tried with using loops and deleting dataframes in between as well as reinstalling python64. But I still have memory issue. Does someone has any solution about solving memory. Using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not renaming the columns prior to the join?
There's nothing wrong with what you do, except for the naming of the columns.
If you have columns with the same name:

```
import pandas as pd

af = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,'A1','B1','C1'],
                        [1,2,'A2','B2','C2'],
                        [1,1,'A3','B3','C3']],
                  columns=['key1', 'key2', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
af = af.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])

bf = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,3,'D3','E3','F3'],
                        [1,4,'D4','E4','F4']],
                  columns=['key1', 'key2', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
bf = bf.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])

result = pd.merge(af, bf, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

yields:

```
             A    B    C    D    E    F
key1 key2                              
1    1      A1   B1   C1  NaN  NaN  NaN
     1      A3   B3   C3  NaN  NaN  NaN
     2      A2   B2   C2  NaN  NaN  NaN
     3     NaN  NaN  NaN   D3   E3   F3
     4     NaN  NaN  NaN   D4   E4   F4
```

If column names are equal:

```
 bf.columns=['A', 'B', 'C']
 result = pd.merge(af, bf, how='outer',on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

you get:

```
           A_x  B_x  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y
key1 key2                              
1    1      A1   B1   C1  NaN  NaN  NaN
     1      A3   B3   C3  NaN  NaN  NaN
     2      A2   B2   C2  NaN  NaN  NaN
     3     NaN  NaN  NaN   D3   E3   F3
     4     NaN  NaN  NaN   D4   E4   F4
```